# Filtered dropdown list based on selection in another dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a simple personnel database in an Excel worksheet. 
It has a lookup table that displays the manager in column A
and their respective employees in column B. 
I want to create two dropdown menus in cells E1 and E2. 
E1 would let me select one of the managers (names from Column A). 
Depending on the manager I select in E1,
I should only get a dropdown list of their employees in E2.

So, for example, if I choose Gary in E1,
then the drop down in E2 will display only Sam and Nick.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manager | Employee |  | Manager: | Gary |
| 2 | Mark | Charles |  | Employee: | Nick |
| 3 | Mark | Derek |  |  |  |
| 4 | Mark | Linda |  |  |  |
| 5 | Gary | Sam |  |  |  |
| 6 | Gary | Nick |  |  |  |
| 7 | Fred | Brian |  |  |  |
| 8 | Fred | Bob |  |  |  |
| 9 | Fred | Julie |  |  |  |
| 10 | Fred | Carl |  |  |  |

The only solution that I could come up with was to create separate columns for each manager, and in each column list out the employees under them. Then I created named ranges for each column. I made the first dropdown a list of unique manager names. And then I used the INDIRECT function in Data Validation to reference the first drop down.

While this works, I am wondering if there is a solution that doesn't require me to create separate columns, as you may understand if there was a new manager or employee added to the lookup table,
I would have to go through these steps again.

Comment: No, there is no other solution outside of vba to having the helper columns.  Though if you have Office 365 you could use FILTER on a single helper column then refer to the spill range.

Comment: @ScottCraner: You’re probably right that there need to be helper columns, but the OP is considering an approach where, if they have 42 managers, they need 42 helper columns, and that *isn’t* necessary.

Comment: infinite_aventura: Do you know how to do the validation for the manager name ``E1``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you willing to have two helper columns
(independent of the number of managers)?

(This solution has been tested with Excel 2013.)

I’ll assume that you have 16 rows of data, in `A2:B17`. 
Adjust the literals in my answer accordingly. 
I’ll assume that you’re using Columns `G` and `H` as your helper columns.

Enter:

- `0` in `G1`,
- `=MATCH($E$1,INDEX($A$2:$A$17,G1+1):$A$17,0)+G1` in `G2`,
- `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$17,G2), "*Zaphod*")` in `H2`, and
- `="H2:H" & MATCH("*Zaphod*",H2:H17,0)` in `H1`.

(Replace `*Zaphod*` with any string that will never appear in your data.) 
Select `G2:H2` and drag/fill down deep
enough to contain the employee list for any manager. 
Then set the validation for `E2` to list, `=INDIRECT(H1)`.

Explanation:

- `G2`, `G3`, `G4`, etc., will contain the index numbers
  within `A2:A17` of the manager name in `E1`. 
  (This will be the row number minus one.)
- `INDEX($A$2:$A$17,G1+1)` identifies the cell below the previous match. 
  For example, for the data in the question,

  - In Row 2, this points to `A2` (since `G1` is zero).
  - In Row 3, this points to `A6` (since `A5` contains “Gary”), and
  - In Row 4, this points to `A7` (since `A6` contains “Gary”).
- `INDEX($A$2:$A$17,G1+1):$A$17` identifies the rest of Column `A`
  (below the previous match).
- `=MATCH($E$1,(the above),0)` finds
  the first occurrence of `E1` in that range; i.e., the *next* occurrence. 
  This will be the `#N/A` error code if there is no next occurrence.
- Add `G1` to convert this back to an index relative to `A2`.
- `INDEX($B$2:$B$17,G2)` gets the employee name
  corresponding to the *n*th occurrence of the manager name in `E1`. 
  If there is no *n*th occurrence,
  the `#N/A` error will propagate through to here.
- `IFERROR` lets us put a dummy value after the real values.
- `MATCH("*Zaphod*",H2:H17,0)` returns the index number
  within `H2:H17` of the dummy value. 
  This will be the row number minus one,
  and so it is the row number of the last real value.
- Append the above to `H2:H` to get the range of valid values.

[image: spreadsheet with data from question except "Fred" in E1]

I’m assuming that you know how to do the validation
for the manager name `E1`. 
If not, see [Dynamic list and count of instances](https://superuser.com/q/940837/150988).

Comment: Thanks for such a simple yet clever solution! I have one question, I was hoping to keep the helper columns on a different tab, but it seems like when I reference it in the data validation, for example =INDIRECT(Sheet2!H1), I get blank in the drop down. Do the helper columns need to be in the same sheet as the dropdown?

Comment: Ach, I should have checked that.  Have you tried setting Sheet2!H1 to ```="Sheet2!H2:H" & MATCH("*Zaphod*",H2:H17,0)```?

Comment: Ah ok, for some reason I thought that would equal ```INDIRECT(Sheet2!Sheet2!H1)``` but now I understand that's not the case. It works fine now, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 365

To filter the column 'Managers' for unique values you would put the following formula in a cell with enough free rows below it to accommodate the total number of managers in your data set as it will populate down.  This cell can be anywhere in your workbook.

Assumptions: You chose cell D5 on the same worksheet for the formula and your table is named 'employeeList'

```
In cell D5 place the formula:            =UNIQUE(employeeList[Manager])  
Alternatively, to order alphabetically:  =SORT(UNIQUE(employeeList[Manager]))
```

This will dynamically generate a list of managers without duplicates.  When the source data updates, the list will also reflect those changes.

Next, you create your drop list validation from that filtered list instead of the employeeList table that contains duplicates.

```
In cell E1 set the following Data Validation:

Settings > Validation criteria
                         Ignore blank:      checked
                         In-cell dropdown:  checked
                         Allow:             List
                         Source:            =D5#
```

The pound symbol (=D5#) indicates to include the SPILL below the cell.